# Pycharm crashes on startup

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

When I try to startup the Pycharm ( pycharm-professional-4.5.4 version), using Ubuntu 15.10  i get this error message.

> Internal error. Please report to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal
>   error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.RegistryState'
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
>       at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:60)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:759)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:712)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:77)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:192)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:106)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:102)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:94)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:83) Caused by:
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal
>   error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.RegistryState'
>       at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:39)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
>       at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
>       at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:125)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:354)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.a(ComponentManagerImpl.java:116)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:87)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:101)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:499)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:481)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:170)
>       ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem.getInstance(LocalFileSystem.java:44)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl$1.beforeFileBasedStorageCreate(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:85)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.a(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:212)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.a(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:185)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.getStateStorage(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:102)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.a(ComponentStoreImpl.java:315)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.java:75)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.initializeComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:177)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:566)
>       ... 27 more Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal
>   error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.ManagingFS'
>       at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:39)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
>       at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
>       at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
>       at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
>       at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
>       at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
>       at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
>       at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
>       at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
>       at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:550)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
>       at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
>       at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
>       at org.picocontainer.defaults.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:268)
>       at org.picocontainer.defaults.CollectionComponentParameter.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:127)
>       at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:116)
>       at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
>       at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
>       at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
>       at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
>       at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:550)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
>       at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
>       at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponentFromContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.java:168)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.getComponentFromContainer(ApplicationImpl.java:533)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:199)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:194)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFileManager.getInstance(VirtualFileManager.java:44)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem$LocalFileSystemHolder.(LocalFileSystem.java:40)
>       ... 36 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/VM
>       at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.(PagedFileStorage.java:58)
>       at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage$StorageLockContext.(PagedFileStorage.java:779)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.c(FSRecords.java:243)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.connect(FSRecords.java:160)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.connect(FSRecords.java:518)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.initComponent(PersistentFSImpl.java:89)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:568)
>       ... 68 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.VM
>       at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:212)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       ... 75 more

I tried to delete the .PyCharm40 folder (I even tried to reinstall the Ubuntu), but the Pycharm just asked me the JetBrains account (student account), and after the authorization the pycharm crashing again.

Comment: Have you reported it to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: So what's your *question?*

Comment: I'm not voting to close this because it's on topic.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider deleting (after taking backup) of `~/.PyCharm*`
I am assuming here you are using Linux or Mac.

Edit: for people with same problem, turns out it was happening because post author was using beta version of Java.

Comment: Yep, i'm using in Ubuntu, and i tried to delete ~/.PyCharm

Comment: and? still crashing? what is the output of `java -version` ?

Comment: java version "9-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+102-2016-01-21-001533.javare.4316.nc)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+102-2016-01-21-001533.javare.4316.nc, mixed mode)
java version "9-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+102-2016-01-21-001533.javare.4316.nc)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+102-2016-01-21-001533.javare.4316.nc, mixed mode)

Comment: You do realize this is alpha / unstable version of Java?

Comment: You're wrong. Updating Java doesn't fix this error!

Comment: when i downgrade the version to stable version is fixed the error